# Multi-threaded parsing with separate proxies using SeleniumBase UC Mode

Tags: multithreading, proxy, seleniumbase

I have a set of 1000-something urls of product pages from an online store. Is there a way to parse them using SeleniumBase UC Mode in a given number of threads, each thread with a separate proxy?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.